# I'm trying to Multithread read all lines with 2 Threads to get diffrent Text instead of same?

Tags: vb.net

The problem is when i Multithread to read all lines it somehow reads the same line with the 2 Threads so i can see in my console "hello1" "hello1" but i want to see 1thread."hello1" 2thread."hello2" 1thread."hello3" 2thread. "hello4" and so one how is that Possible?

to read the lines im using this:

```
 For Each element As String In File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")
 console.writeline(element)
 next
```

Comment: Your procedure is doing what you instructed it to do: read all the lines from a file and show the content of each. Why would a thread *skip* some of the lines (odd/even) if you didn't code it? Maybe, use a `For` loop and take the line only if the indexer is odd/even.

Comment: idk mate just asking if its working somehow i saw some dope proxy checkers that use multi threads how to they skip the lines?

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this in a multithreaded way?

Comment: im coding a checker i need to send multiple requests per sec

Comment: Files don't have lines--text does.  So, if it's a text file, the text contained in the file can be multi-line, but there's nothing inherently built into the file system, at least not in any file system I'm aware of, which supports reading lines, by index, from a text file.  The only way to do it is to read all the text, look for end-of-line characters, and parse them into separate lines.  At that point, having multiple threads gains nothing because each thread is still having to read all the text even if it's throwing out half of them because they are odd or even.

Comment: I suggest that you first make the program work and then, if necessary, find where it could take advantage of multiple threads. It may be easier to see that once the program has been written.

Comment: You could have one `StreamReader` being used by both threads, so that when one reads a line, it advances the position on the stream so that when the next thread reads, it picks up where the other left off, but both would be sharing the same file stream, so it's not going to read from disk any quicker.  That only helps if it's the processing of the data in the lines that is slow.  In any case, you couldn't share a thread between two threads like that without adding thread-synchronization logic which could slow things down.

Comment: *I'm coding a checker* doesn't mean much. If you need concurrent readings on a single file, you need to have concurrent streams that read from different positions specific chunks of data (paired with a good *seeker*). Or a [MemoryMappedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile), which allows concurrent processing by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more efficient ways to do it, but try this...

```
' Custom "indexes"
Dim t1Count As Integer = 1
Dim t2Count As Integer = 1

' In Thread #1
For Each Element As String In File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")
    ' Index is odd
    If Not t1Count Mod 2 = 0 Then
        console.writeline(element)
    End If

    t1Count += 1
Next

' In Thread #2
For Each Element As String In File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")
    ' Index is even
    If t2Count Mod 2 = 0 Then
        console.writeline(element)
    End If

    t2Count += 1
Next
```